# ¿Mostrar cuadrado agregado dentro de svg de HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, svg

Quiero que al dar click dentro del cuadrado gris, se dibuje un cuadrado en de 10px x 10px en el lugar que hice click, agrego el elemento dentro del SVG, pero no lo dibuja.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" id="cuadro" class="map-row" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;" onmousemove="moveMouse(event)" onclick="drawRect(event)">
        <rect x="460" y="130" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="460" y="120" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="460" y="110" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="470" y="110" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="470" y="120" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
    </svg>

<script>
    function moveMouse(event){
        //console.log(event.clientX+"-"+event.clientY);
    }

    function drawRect(event){
        console.log("click");
        console.log(event.clientX+"-"+event.clientY);
        printRect(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    }

    function printRect(x,y){
        $("#cuadro").append(`<rect x="${x}" y="${y}" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>`);
    }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/1423096

Al pasarle un string a `$` se interpreta con la propiedad `.innerHTML` propia del navegador, la cual no interpreta SVG u otro elemento no-HTML y además no sabe que "`<rect>`" es parte del espacio SVG.

Da dos soluciones, transcribo la primera:

```js
 function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
            var el= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
            for (var k in attrs)
                el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
            return el;
        }
 
 function moveMouse(event){
        //console.log(event.clientX+"-"+event.clientY);
    }

    function drawRect(event){
        console.log("click");
        console.log(event.clientX+"-"+event.clientY);
        printRect(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    }

    function printRect(x,y){
       var rect= makeSVG("rect", {x: x, y:y, width:10, height:10, fill:"#c4ecea", stroke:"#3B4152", style:"stroke-width: 0.5px"})
        document.getElementById("cuadro").appendChild(rect);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" id="cuadro" class="map-row" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;" onmousemove="moveMouse(event)" onclick="drawRect(event)">
        <rect x="460" y="130" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="460" y="120" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="460" y="110" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="470" y="110" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
        <rect x="470" y="120" width="10" height="10" fill="#c4ecea" stroke="#3B4152" style="stroke-width: 0.5px" ></rect>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

En resumen: Se crea un nodo SVG y se lo adiciona como child al SVG principal, esquivando al jQuery.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.